# Why is my custom UITableViewCell null in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;
    if (self.tableView == tableView)
    {
        numberOfRows = self.allMovies.count;
        NSLog(@"NRA:%d", self.allMovies.count);
    }
    else
    {
        [self filterPlayers];
        numberOfRows = self.filteredMovies.count;
        NSLog(@"NRF:%d", self.filteredMovies.count);
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchAndAddMovieCell";
    FFFSearchAndAddMovieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell is nil");
        cell = [[FFFSearchAndAddMovieCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
            NSLog(@"Still NIL");
    }

    Movie *movie;
    if (self.tableView == tableView)
    {
        Movie *normalMovie = (Movie *)[self.allMovies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        movie = normalMovie;
        NSLog(@"normal:%@", movie);
    }
    else
    {
        Movie *filteredMovie = [self.filteredMovies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        movie = filteredMovie;
        NSLog(@"filter:%@", movie);
    }

    NSLog(@"1:%@|%@", movie.name, cell.movieName.text);
    cell.movieName.text = movie.name;
    NSLog(@"2:%@|%@", movie.name, cell.movieName.text);
    cell.genre.text = movie.genre;
```

This populates my initial list of movies perfectly fine. However, when I type a character into the UISearchBar that I have about my UITableViewController, I don't get any results, despite seeing would-be/should-be results in my NSLog. Any ideas?

Here is the LOG output...

```
2014-02-24 17:15:24.274 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] NRF:1
2014-02-24 17:15:24.278 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] Cell is nil
2014-02-24 17:15:24.281 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] filter:The Godfather
2014-02-24 17:15:24.283 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 1:The Godfather|(null)
2014-02-24 17:15:24.286 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 2:The Godfather|(null)
```

Why is cell.movieName.text continually null here? Before I type anything into the searchBar, the LOG looks like this...

```
2014-02-24 17:15:22.015 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] NRA:12
2014-02-24 17:15:22.021 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] normal:The Godfather
2014-02-24 17:15:22.023 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 1:The Godfather|Label
2014-02-24 17:15:22.024 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 2:The Godfather|The Godfather
```

These are the ones I'm curious about in bold. Normal run has them like the bottom 2, but the searchBar run has them as the top 2.

2014-02-24 17:15:24.283 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 1:The Godfather|**(null)**

2014-02-24 17:15:24.286 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 2:The Godfather|**(null)**

2014-02-24 17:15:22.023 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 1:The Godfather|**Label**

2014-02-24 17:15:22.024 FantasyFeed[2367:60b] 2:The Godfather|**The Godfather**

Answer (score 1):

Your code suggests that you have two separate tables. I suspect they're both in your storyboard file and that one has a prototype cell with an identifier of `SearchAndAddMovieCell` while the other does not.

Comment: Hmmm. I have a UITableViewController. In storyboard, it's Identifier is SearchAndAddMovieCell. Above that I have a Search Bar and Search Display Controller. I guess that does have it's own tableView... but there doesn't appear to be a place in Storyboard to add the Identifier. Should there be? Is that what I'm missing?

Comment: I changed     
     FFFSearchAndAddMovieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
to
     FFFSearchAndAddMovieCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

And now it works. I'm assuming this should be fine as the results table will never have more cells than the original full table of self.tableView, correct?